# Why is this VBA find function not finding the search string?

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am using VBA in excel, and I am trying to find the text "Summary", without the quotes, in a cell. The cell is in the first colum, and I want find which row it is in. I know it is there, I see it when I look at the workbook. However, my condition 'If Not found Is Nothing Then' does not execute, implying the value was not found. What is wrong with my find, how can I fix this. Thanks.

```
Sub RemoveFooterRows(theFile)
Dim found As Range
Set found = Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Find _
    ("Summary", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False)


If Not found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("val is inif " & found.Row)
 '   Workbooks(theFile).Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible there's a hidden sheet in your workbook? If it was the first sheet then that would explain your issue.  Can you reference by name instead?

Comment: It does not even have to be hidden, a sheet named "Sheet3" might, in fact, be sheet number 4 and a reference to Sheet3 or Worksheets(3) will fail.

Comment: It may be possible to reference it by name, although I would prefer not to. The sheet name could change, although it hasn't yet. Is there a way to reference the 1st non-hidden sheet? I don't beleive there are any hidden sheets, though. How would I check?

Comment: @Remou There is only 1 sheet, that I know of, so is it then safe to assume it is Worksheets(1)

Comment: I'm with the group on this, I resist ever referencing sheets by index number this way, the one thing I know I have 100% control over is the sheetnames.  I would use the sheet name.

Comment: I just tested it on my side, seems to be working fine though. Couple of questions: 1. Is the value in the first column? 2. Do you have to pass the file as a parameter? In my case I embedded the macro in the worksheet, eliminated both the Workbooks(theFile) reference and the parameter.

Comment: @ Jerry I have 0% control over the sheetname, or it wouldn't be an issue. I am not creating the excel file. It is being processed hands off.

Comment: @DigCamara The value is in A5183, so yes, the first column. Yes, I have to pass the file as the parameter, the workbook containing the macro is not the workbook being modified. IS there anything else that could cause it to fail?

Comment: I passed excelfile.xls and your code worked for me.

Comment: Further, to rule out the issue of the sheet being incorrectly reference, I have other code referencing it the same way, and it functions correctly.

Comment: Worked as in I found the value and furthermore, i ran from a different workbook.

Comment: I just stuck "Summary" in cell A1, in cell A18, within the data, and left the occurence at cell A5183 alone. In this case the code worked, but it told me it was at row 18, ignoring the occurence in A1. Why is this, and could it be a hint as to why the single occurence at the bottom is not being found?

Comment: In stepping through with the workbook as before, I manually re-entered "Summary" into the cell I am looking for, to ensure there were no funky spaces or anything, and it still isn't finding it.

Comment: How about: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/FindAll.aspx

Comment: @Remou When the value in A5183 is the only occurence, it isn't found. It's not as though another occurence is found instead

Comment: I am failing to reproduce this error, sorry.

Comment: I tested a few things to ensure the proper column is referenced     Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Select
    MsgBox (Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Rows(4).Value)                                                             The first is supposed to select A column, but it appears to select everything ,this could be a hint at the issue. The second statement displays the proper value from that row in column A, it appears to work properly.

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in your worksheet? In my quick test, Find() fails if the value is in a merged cell which spans >1 column. Search range needs to completely include the merge area for Find() to work?

Comment: Brian can you post your workbook(sanitised if necessary) somewhere on the web?

Comment: I'll throw a coulple more suggestions on the pile (admittedly low %age ones). Your are not specifying Matchbyte which is a "remembered" find attribute. Second you may want to try running the find function manually to see if it is your code particularly. Third I would check the data type associated with the summary cell.

Comment: @Tim WIlliams. It is merged, that is likely the issue. How can that be dealt with?

Comment: @Brian - you'd need to unmerge the cells, enlarge your search range, or search "manually" by looping through the cells' values

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub RemoveFooterRows(theFile)

    Dim res As Variant, ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets

        res = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Summary", ws.Range("A:A"), 0)
        If IsEmpty(res) = False Then
            MsgBox "Val is inif " & res
            GoTo Skip
        End If

    Next ws
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```